# Prove or disprove $\frac{1}{5}(3-4i)$ is a root of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, roots-of-unity

Prove or disprove $\frac{1}{5}(3-4i)$ is a root of unity.

Here is the definition of root of unity:

An nth root of unity, where $n$ is a positive integer $(i.e. n = 1, 2, 3, …)$, is a number $z$ satisfying the equation $z^n=1$.

Comment: We can also say that $2\pi$ is not an integral multiple of $\arctan(\frac{4}{3})$.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this; roots of unity are algebraic integers
but this number $\alpha$ isn't. Or you could show the denominator of $\alpha^n$ is always $5^n$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a root of unity. Since $(3+i)(3+i)=8+6i\equiv 3+i \pmod{5}$
it follows that for any positive integer $n$,
$$(3-4i)^n\equiv (3+i)^n\equiv 3+i \pmod{5}$$
which contradicts the fact that $(3-4i)^m=5^m$ for some positive integer $m$.

Comment: Why do we need to say "since $(3+i)(3+i)=...$? I think we can directly conclude that $(3-4i)^n$ is congruent to $(3+i)^n$ because $-4=1$ modulo $5$?

Comment: @zero field The "since ..." is needed to show that $(3+i)^n\equiv 3+i$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the exponential form.

We have $\displaystyle q=e^{i\tan^{-1}\left(-\frac{4}{3}\right)}$

All roots of unity are of the form $z=e^{i\left(\frac{2π}{n}\right)}$.

This is because they are all solutions of $z^n=1$.

Notice that $\tan^{-1}(-\frac{4}{3})$ is not in this form, and thus $q$ is not a root of unity.

Comment: `Notice that ... is not in this form` How do you "*notice*" that?

Comment: To be more specific, all roots of unity are of the form $z=e^{i\left(\frac{2kπ}{n}\right)}$ where $1\leq k<n$